# Correct Part for Connect an Two-Pin LED or Switch

Tags: led, connector, wiring, header

Quite simply what I'd like to know is, what is the technical information for the male connector that corresponds to the following plug:

[image]

The male connectors (headers?) are commonly found on computer devices such as motherboards, and are used for connecting LEDs or switches, usually on a computer's case. However, the device I'm working doesn't include these connections, so I'd like to provide them myself by adding a suitable pair of male pins to the end of the correct wires, rather than having to wire in an LED or switch directly, I'm just not sure exactly what I'm looking for, is there a common male connector I can just add to a pair of wires?

Apologies for my lack of more specific terminology, usually when I work with computers I have all the parts I need or can just order some up :)

Answer (score 2):

Those are typically plugged into **0.1" header pins** on a PC motherboard or similar PCB.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a 100mil (2.54mm) pitch square male pin header, they are available is several lengths and can be cut as required

[image: 100mil pin male header]